# How to fix Binding element 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm getting the following error: Binding element 'post' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
when I'm mapping post:

This component was taken from a guide for setting up a blog component. I've adapted it to typescript. But I'm very new to both React and Typescript. Everything works as expected it's just I'm unsure how to make this line of code 'typescript friendly'. I've tried adding a type declaration for post within the .map, but it throws more errors.

```
.map(({ node: post }) => {
```

**blog.tsx**

```
type BlogProps = {
  data?: any;
};

const BlogPage: React.FC<BlogProps> = (props) => {
  const { edges: posts } = props.data.allMarkdownRemark;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Seo title="Blog" />
      <div className="blog-posts container">
        {posts
          .filter((post: any) => post.node.frontmatter.title.length > 0)
          .map(({ node: post }) => {
            return (
              <div className="blog-post-preview" key={post.id}>
                <h1>
                  <Link to={post.frontmatter.path}>
                    {post.frontmatter.title}
                  </Link>
                </h1>
                <h2>{post.frontmatter.date}</h2>
                <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

**Edit**

The fix was to define the type for the data property - thanks Aluan.

Ended up defining edges with an interface:

```
type BlogProps = {
  data: {
    allMarkdownRemark: {
      edges: IEdge[];
    };
  };
};

interface IEdge {
  node: {
    excerpt: string;
    id: string;
    frontmatter: {
      title: string;
      path: string;
      date: string;
    };
  };
}`
```

This was my graphql query:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 250)
          id
          frontmatter {
            title
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            path
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: By specifying a well defined type for the `data` property. Ex: `data: { allMarkdownRemark: { edges: Array<{node: Node }>} }`  you need to figure out what  `Node` should be. I don't know what you're working with.

Comment: I ended up defining the Node in an interface - added code to question